# Clear the review queue :-)

Tags: discussion, reviews

Just a quick heads-up. We have 181 users with the [Access Review Queue](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege (350+).

Currently, there are 17 items in the [queue for review](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/review). Most of them are first post and close votes!

First posts are very, *very* important to help on-boarding new users and ensure the questions asked are respecting the site topic and the Stack Exchange format.

Please, keep checking the review queues regularly! And if you happen to have the [Moderator Tools](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) already, please also review the reviews (Reviews -> Recent -> History)! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I endorse your appeal**, 
Recently I've noticed there is a raise of the new posts posted by people who are new to stackexchange. These people are not certainly aware of this forum's rules, and they need assistance and help (they generally can't upvote or comment everywhere).

On my side the review section is the first place i check. With a limitation of approving 20 new post, I get many time stuck ,after reaching the limit, for many hours before continuing the approval process. 
[image]
Concerning **closing** posts, I think we need additional efforts, unless the post is not a spam or duplicated we should leave it open to give a chance to the requester, by editing the post or asking questions in the comments.

another point some times we have a big number of non reviewed posts due to the time lag.

Thanks to all the reviewers for their efforts.

Comment: Agree with not closing everything first. The best step is to comment and suggest improvements. Most questions can be salvaged anyways.